# Why is save not a function after assigning properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

TypeError: newUser.save is not a function (in the createNew function)

Before assigning the properties with the spread operator, the userModel object has a save function (as designed by mongoose), however after the assign the function cannot be accessed anymore. Can someone explain why this is and how to get around it?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  facebookid: String,
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  timezone: Number,
  gender: String,
  invitationid: String,
  referralid: String,
  locale: String,
  stage: String
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

const createUser = () => new User()

module.exports = {
  createNew : userInfo => {

    const userModel = createUser()

    const newUser =  { ...userModel,
      facebookid: userInfo.fid,
      firstname: userInfo.first_name,
      lastname: userInfo.last_name,
      locale: userInfo.locale,
      timezone: userInfo.timezone,
      gender: userInfo.gender,
      invitationid: userInfo.invitationid,
      referralid: userInfo.referralid,
      stage: 'NA'
    }
    return newUser.save()
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!
Mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass object while creating new user :-

```
module.exports = {
createNew : userInfo => {

const userModel = createUser({
  facebookid: userInfo.fid,
  firstname: userInfo.first_name,
  lastname: userInfo.last_name,
  locale: userInfo.locale,
  timezone: userInfo.timezone,
  gender: userInfo.gender,
  invitationid: userInfo.invitationid,
  referralid: userInfo.referralid,
  stage: 'NA'
})

return userModel.save()
}
}
```

And Modify

```
createUser = (user) => new User(user)
```

Now the userModel contains the user returned by mongoose orm and you can access save function.Earlier you weren't using the user object returned by mongoose, you were creating new one

Comment: I was not aware of that parameter of the constructor. Elegant solution and works perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `newUser` is not a `User` object.

`...userModel` will only merge object "**own**" properties not the prototype.

Try something like this :

```
const newUser = new User({/* your user */});
newUser.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a detail, concerning the problem and not a possible solution

with `{...userModel}` you're copying the direct properties of the `User` instance into a **plain object**. Any property or method inherited from extended classes will be ignored and, most importantly, the prototype chain itself will be lost.

the `save()` method is probably defined in the `Schema` class from moongoose, so you lose it with that technique.

Any of the proposed solutions in the other answers will fix the problem just fine.